# Bootstrap for Swift or something to make layout easier

Tags: swift, layout

I am struggling with layout in Swift for text views and having multiple text views on a screen.

Is there something like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for swift?

Alternatively do you have a suggestion on how to get really good and layout/design/styling for text in Swift?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes some getting used to when it comes to layouts. I usually watch autolayout videos instead of reading tutorials. Example below. Its a little different from CSS. Spend some time learning the autolayouts and you dont need to worry about bootstraps or anything. You will be able to smoothly get things properly alligned.
[Auto Layout Videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mOuKvuVgUv0&list=PLRbmF7J5CbMPcMU3oe37uyZuZXeoBOB1_)